# What is the meaning of an "asset column" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is the context. The person the people below speak of is a journalist who was convicted for Libel.

Salander: He’s honest.  He’s who he presents himself to be.  In his business, that’s an asset.
FRODE: There’s less in his **asset column** after his conviction today.

What is an asset column in this context? Is there an asset column in a curriculum vitae? This is what I thought he was alluding to but was unable to find it in any cv.

"Column" noun (source:Thefreedictionary)
a. any of two or more vertical sections of type on a printed page, esp on a newspaper page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to "columns" in a spreadsheet or other accounting table. An accountant handling finances, even in days before computers, would add up "assets" in a vertical column to be totaled (and, in other columns, "liabilities" or debts or withdrawals). As we see in [definition 6 of this entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/column), that meaning can be extended to non-financial matters:

> : a statistical category or grouping
> *// put another game in the win column*

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a sort of accounting metaphor. His reputation is now tarnished, i.e. his libel conviction (or at least the libel itself) made a significant withdrawal from his reputation for honesty.

Comment: I understand the sense of the sentence but the question I asked was " what does an asset column mean.

Comment: @StaticBounce - it's a metaphor. There is no column anywhere. In an an **imaginary** table of his personal qualities, there might be an equally imaginary column headed 'assets' and it might contain 'reputation for honesty: 10 points'. Now that number must be smaller because of his court appearance, says Frode.